# appending numbers to string within a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string the following code:

```
list_k = [23,5,2,5,76,34,32,12,43,6]
for number in range((len(list_k)):
    the_string="The number is " + str(number)
    print the_string
```

Intended output:

```
The number is 23
The number is 5
The number is 2
...
The number is 43
The number is 6
```

I cant seem to figure out why I am not getting that output, when I dont include the range, I get a type error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `format`

```
for num in list_k:
    print('The number is {}'.format(num))
```

The problem with your existing code is that if you are using `range(len(list_k))` you are iterating over indices, so you'd need to index out the number from the list with `list_k[number]`

```
for number in range((len(list_k)):
    the_string="The number is " + str(list_k[number])
    print the_string
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is:

```
list_k = [23,5,2,5,76,34,32,12,43,6]
for number in list_k:
    the_string="The number is " + str(number)
    print the_string
```

to directly iterate through the list.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in your code is that `range((len(list_k))` is a list from 0 to `len(List_k)  - 1`, so `num` will interate over the values `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., len(list_k) -1`, instead of the elements of `list_k` as intended

Comment: is this because `len(list_k)` is an integer which is the number of items in the list and the range is from 0 to that number?

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
for number in range(len(list_k)):
    print "the number is %d" % number
```

Comment: You missed the point: The question is not about the formatting itself but about iterating over the `list_k` properly so its values appear in the output.

Comment: That would surprise me. `for number in range(...)` iterates over `0,1,2,3,...`. How does this output relate to the intended output in the question?

Comment: Try this: print "string is " + str(list_k[number] )

Comment: Yes I know. Also other answers already explain it. My point is: This answer is wrong and since there are correct answers already, it would be best to just remove this one.